# awk to print text in field based on coordinate range and exact match

Tags: awk

In the awk below I am trying to match the value in `$4` of `file1` with the value from `$4` in `file2` before the first `_`. I store the value of `$4` in `file1` in `A`. I then strore the value in `$2` as `min`, the value in `$3` as `max`, and the value in `$1` as `chr`.
If `$1 in A` is equal to `array[1]`, then i use the values stored in `min`, `max`, and `chr` to check if there is overlap or not between the `$2`, `$3`, and `$`1 values in `file2`. If there is then `overlap` is printed but if there is not `missing` is printed. I am trying to ensure that the lines match and that the coordinates are in covered from `file1` to `file2`. My actual data is several thousands of lines all in the below format and a match should result for each line in `file2`. I commented the `awk` as well and hope it helps as I am get syntax errors and maybe there is a better way, but I wanted to try and see.

If I remove the `{split($4,array,"_")}` and remove `array[1]`, I get the current output, but not all lines are printed only the `overlap` lines are and I'm not sure only the exact match will be printed.

**file1**   `tab-delimited`

```
chr19   42373737    42373856    RPS19
chr6    32790021    32790140    TAP2
```

**file2**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr19   42364844    42364915    RPS19_cds_1_0_chr19_42364845_f  0   +
chr19   42365180    42365281    RPS19_cds_2_0_chr19_42365181_f  0   +
chr19   42373100    42373284    RPS19_cds_3_0_chr19_42373101_f  0   +
chr19   42373768    42373823    RPS19_cds_4_0_chr19_42373769_f  0   +
chr19   42375418    42375445    RPS19_cds_5_0_chr19_42375419_f  0   +
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr19   42364844    42364915    RPS19_cds_1_0_chr19_42364845_f  0   +     missing
chr19   42365180    42365281    RPS19_cds_2_0_chr19_42365181_f  0   +     missing 
chr19   42373100    42373284    RPS19_cds_3_0_chr19_42373101_f  0   +     missing
chr19   42373768    42373823    RPS19_cds_4_0_chr19_42373769_f  0   +     overlap
chr19   42375418    42375445    RPS19_cds_5_0_chr19_42375419_f  0   +     missing
```

**awk**

```
awk ' # call awk script
 BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }  # define FS and OFS as tab
  FNR==NR{  # start processing same line in files
   a[$4];  # store gene in 
   min[$4]=$2;  # store staring coordinate
   max[$4]=$3;  # store ending coordinate
    next         # process next line
}  # close block
 {  # start block
   split($4,array,"_");   # split $4 on _ and store in array[1]
   print $0,(array[1] in a) && ($2>=min[array[1]] && 
$2<=max[array[1]])?"overlap":"missing" # print all lines followed by 
overlap or missing depending on condition (if array[1] = a and $2 in 
file2 is greater than or equal to min and $3 in file2 greater than or 
equal to max print overlap, else missing)
}  # close block
' file1 file2  # define input
```

**current output**

```
1   42373768    42373823    RPS19_cds_4_0_chr19_42373769_f  0   +   overlap
```

Comment: That `if(…) { $ match gene in file 1` should have a `#` in place of the `$` unless you're trying something I don't understand.  I've fixed your markdown syntax a bit already.  It'd help if your code were narrow enough to be visible without horizontal scrolling, too.

Comment: Your indentation implies your final `next` is a second command inside your `for` loop, but it's actually inside your `if` statement (as is your no-op command of `"missing"`).  Then again, your other `next` is also oddly indented, so maybe that's your intent. I think if you re-indent and explicitly apply curly brackets (e.g. to the `for` loop, rather than using implicit grouping), you may find your problem.

Comment: Telling us "I am get syntax errors" without actually posting the syntax errors is not useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go super star `awk` to rescue here:
Also couldn't see your Input_file(s) are actual TAB delimited so use `FS="\t"` before `Input_file1` in this code too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4];min[$4]=$2;max[$4]=$3;next} {split($4,array,"_");print $0,(array[1] in a) && ($2>=min[array[1]] && $2<=max[array[1]])?"overlap":"missing"}'  Input_file1  OFS="\t"   Input_file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution now too:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$4];
  min[$4]=$2;
  max[$4]=$3;
  next
}
{
  split($4,array,"_");
  print $0,(array[1] in a) && ($2>=min[array[1]] && $2<=max[array[1]])?"overlap":"missing"
}
'  Input_file1  OFS="\t"  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows:

```
chr19   42364844    42364915    RPS19_cds_1_0_chr19_42364845_f  0   +   missing
chr19   42365180    42365281    RPS19_cds_2_0_chr19_42365181_f  0   +   missing
chr19   42373100    42373284    RPS19_cds_3_0_chr19_42373101_f  0   +   missing
chr19   42373768    42373823    RPS19_cds_4_0_chr19_42373769_f  0   +   overlap
chr19   42375418    42375445    RPS19_cds_5_0_chr19_42375419_f  0   +   missing
```